# how to right click to save picture or file?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wirte a pyqt5 code to show picture or file from our local computer. After this, I have no idea to save the picture or file showed in window on other path. The only way I figured out is copy them. Any suggestion or tips would be appreciated.

Here is the code to show picture or file:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class fileDialogdemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(fileDialogdemo, self).__init__(parent)
        layout=QVBoxLayout()

        self.btn=QPushButton("Load Picture")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.getimage)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.le=QLabel('')
        layout.addWidget(self.le)

        self.btn1=QPushButton('Load text file')
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.getFiles)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1)

        self.contents=QTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.contents)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle('File Dialog ')

    def getimage(self):
        image_file,_=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open file','C:\\','Image files (*.jpg *.gif *.png *.jpeg)')
        self.le.setPixmap(QPixmap(image_file))

    def getFiles(self):
        dig=QFileDialog()
        dig.setFileMode(QFileDialog.AnyFile)
        dig.setFilter(QDir.Files)

        if dig.exec_():
            filenames=dig.selectedFiles()
            f=open(filenames[0],'r')

            with f:
                data=f.read()
                self.contents.setText(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex=fileDialogdemo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the code to save I am trying, but there is something wrong:

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    cmenu = QMenu(self)
    saveAct = cmenu.addAction("Save as")
    action = cmenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
    if action == saveAct:
        filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
        shutil.copyfile(self.image_file, filename)
```

Except for the copy idea, is there any better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not copy the image as nobody guarantees that after loading the image the original image is in the same location or still exists. Instead, retrieve the QPixmap from the QLabel and save it:

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    cmenu = QMenu(self)
    saveAct = cmenu.addAction("Save as")
    action = cmenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
    if action == saveAct:
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
        pixmap = self.le.pixmap()
        if pixmap is not None and filename:
            pixmap.save(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for picture. In addition, how do I save content from QTableWidget? Is there any method to obtain them as QLable.pixmap? If not, I have save them using loop as I showed them ?